Cannot pass custom headers to a ballerina RabbitMQ publish message other than the ones defined in the BasicProperties
I trying out the Ballerina programming language in combination with the RabbitMQ client where I want to pass custom headers with the message. On the publish message function I can only pass BasicProperties, which can only accept:

replyTo
correlationId
contentType
contentEncoding

However we rely heavily on custom headers as we route message based on them and in the standard RabbitMQ client this is supported on the BasicProperties object on the headers dictionary collection. Is this a gap in the RabbitMQ Ballerina client?
Created a Ballerina file and tried to publish to RabbitMQ, but I miss the headers property on the BasicProperties object.
rabbitmq:BasicProperties props = {
    replyTo: "reply-queue",
    // Expect headers property in the form of a dictionary
};

// Publishes the message using the `newClient` and the routing key named `OrderQueue`.
check self.orderClient->publishMessage({
    content: newOrder,
    routingKey: "",
    properties: props
});
    
return http:ACCEPTED;

